# React/Hooks extra undefined field upon submission

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm getting a really weird return error that on submission I randomly add an extra duplicate field somehow which is of course then undefined. The input value is also randomly copied from one of the other fields within the form.

```
const GameForm = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:6060/games'

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value, year, rating, developer } = e.target
        setGameData({ ...gameData, [name]: value, [year]: value, [rating]: value, [developer]: value })
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { name, year, rating, developer } = gameData

        if (!name || !year || !rating || !developer) return

        console.log(gameData)

        axios
            .post(url, gameData)
            .then((res) => {
                setGameData(res)
            }).catch((error) => console.log(error))

    }

    const [gameData, setGameData] = useState({ name: '', year: 0, rating: '', developer: "" })

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <label id="name" htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Game title" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="year">Year: </label>
            <input type="number" name="year" placeholder="Release year" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="rating">Rating: </label>
            <input type="text" name="rating" placeholder="Age rating" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="developer">Developer: </label>
            <input type="text" name="developer" placeholder="Developer" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Console logged return: (I also get a 500 error obviously)

```
{name: "1", year: "1", rating: "1", developer: "1", undefined: "1"}
```

The undefined value is seemingly taken from any of the existing fields at random.

I feel like I am likely overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Maybe the problem is defining state later. You called state gameData and setGameData above but you defined later that they are actually state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-using `e.target`. It will not have all the properties that you try to destruct from it. From the ones you list in your example code, it will only have `name` and `value`, all the other ones (rating, year, developer) will be `undefined` as they are not part of the event's target property.

The reason you only get one `undefined` value in your state object is because it keeps overriding itself when you set your state.

The property from the event target you are trying to access is `name`, so in your case basically `e.target.name`

Anyway, with that in mind the fix for your app will be quite simple:

```js
 const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        
       // Note: The name will hold whatever value of the name prop you put on your input.
       // When you are editing the input with the name prop set to name, it will be "name"
       // For the input with the name prop set to "year", it will be "year:
       // For the input with the name prop set to "developer" it will be "developer" and so on.
        setGameData({ ...gameData, [name]: value })
    }
```

Here is a demo for you with the fix:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [gameData, setGameData] = React.useState({ name: '', year: 0, rating: '', developer: "" })


    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        
        setGameData({ ...gameData, [name]: value })
    }

  return (
  <div>
              <label id="name" htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Game title" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="year">Year: </label>
            <input type="number" name="year" placeholder="Release year" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="rating">Rating: </label>
            <input type="text" name="rating" placeholder="Age rating" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="developer">Developer: </label>
            <input type="text" name="developer" placeholder="Developer" onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <br />
                <button onClick={() => console.warn('GAME DATA OBJECT', gameData)}>Click</button>

  </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```